# Rails 5: Render a div for each child object in a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to have reddit style nested comments on a page. I've got everything set up the way I want. But, I'm having trouble figuring out how to render comments in an efficient manner. See my current partial below:

```
#_comment_list.html.erb
<div class="comment-list">
  <h2>Comments</h2>
  <ul>
    <% @post.comments.each do |c| %>
        <% byebug %>
      <li><%= c.body %></li>
      <% unless c.is_deleted == true %>
        <%= render partial: "shared/comment_form", :locals => { commentable_type: c.class.name, commentable_id: c.id, post: @post.id } if current_user %>
      <% end %>
      <ul>
        <% c.comments.each do |d| %>
          <li><%= d.body %></li>
          <% unless d.is_deleted == true %>
            <%= render partial: "shared/comment_form", :locals => { commentable_type: d.class.name, commentable_id: d.id, post: @post.id } if current_user %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Obviously, this will only render only one set of child comments like so:

```
Post
  Comment
    Child Comment
    Child Comment
  Comment
  ...
```

I'm drawing a blank, design wise, on how to render children of child comments for as many times as they need to be nested.

```
Post
  Comment
    Child Comment
      Grandchild Comment
        Great Grandchild Comment
        Great Grandchild Comment
    Child Comment
  Comment
  ...
```

If someone could point me in a direction of where to go, I would be much appreciated.

Here is some info about my models and associations if it would help come up with a solution.

```
# Comment.rb
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :body
  # validates :user_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable

  def find_parent_post
    return self.commentable if self.commentable.is_a?(Post)
    self.commentable.find_parent_post # semi recursion will keep calling itself until it .is_a? Post
  end
end

# Post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :forum_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :forum

  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.text     "body"
  t.datetime "created_at",                       null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                       null: false
  t.integer  "commentable_id"
  t.string   "commentable_type"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.boolean  "is_deleted",       default: false, null: false
end

create_table "forums", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.text     "description"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_forums_on_user_id", using: :btree
end

create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "description"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "forum_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  t.index ["forum_id"], name: "index_posts_on_forum_id", using: :btree
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id", using: :btree
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways to do it:

Create a partial that references itself for child comments, like:

```
# comments/_show.html.erb

<% depth ||= 0 %>
<div class="comment" style="padding-left: <%= 16 * depth %>px;">
  <%= comment.text %>
  <% comment.children.each do |c| %>
    <%= render partial: "comments/show", locals: { comment: c, depth: depth + 1 } %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

---

Or you can modify your Comment model to have a natural nesting at the database level, and query/order/indent them all at once. This is more complicated, but it's extremely powerful and extremely easy to use.

Add a `tree_left`, `tree_right` and `depth` column to your comments table (all positive integers). Index the `tree` columns.

`tree_left` and `tree_right` are mutually unique and contain every number from 1 to (Number of records * 2). Here is an example tree:

```
test# select id, text, parent, tree_left, tree_right, depth from comments order by tree_left;
+----+----------------------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+
| id | text                       | parent    | tree_left | tree_right | depth |
+----+----------------------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+
|  1 | Top Level Comment          |      NULL |         1 |         30 |     0 |
|  2 | Second Level               |         1 |         2 |         29 |     1 |
|  3 | Third Level 1              |         2 |         3 |         20 |     2 |
|  5 | Fourth Level 1             |         3 |         4 |          9 |     3 |
| 12 | Fifth Level 4              |         5 |         5 |          6 |     4 |
| 13 | Fifth Level 5              |         5 |         7 |          8 |     4 |
|  6 | Fourth Level 2             |         3 |        10 |         19 |     3 |
|  8 | Fifth Level                |         6 |        11 |         18 |     4 |
|  9 | Sixth Level 1              |         8 |        12 |         13 |     5 |
| 10 | Sixth Level 2              |         8 |        14 |         15 |     5 |
| 11 | Sixth Level 3              |         8 |        16 |         17 |     5 |
|  4 | Third Level 2              |         2 |        21 |         28 |     2 |
|  7 | Fourth Level 3             |         4 |        22 |         27 |     3 |
| 14 | Fifth Level 6              |         7 |        23 |         24 |     4 |
| 15 | Fifth Level 7              |         7 |        25 |         26 |     4 |
+----+----------------------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+
```

Insert top level comments with `depth = 0`, `tree_left = (current largest tree_right + 1)` and `tree_right = (current largest tree_right + 2)`.

Insert child comments with `depth = parent.depth + 1`, `tree_left = parent.tree_right`, and `tree_right = parent.tree_right +`. THEN, run:

`UPDATE comments SET tree_left  = tree_left  + 2 WHERE tree_left  >= #{parent.tree_right}`
`UPDATE comments SET tree_right = tree_right + 2 WHERE tree_right >= #{parent.tree_right}`

Comment `A` is a child of comment `B` if and only if:
  `A.tree_left > B.tree_left`, and `A.tree_right < B.tree_right`.

So the way this works is you can get all children in the tree belonging to comment "XYZ" with this query:

`Select * from comments where tree_left >= #{XYZ.tree_left} AND tree_right <= #{XYZ.tree_right} ORDER BY tree_left`.

To get all the PARENTS of a comment, use the opposite signs:

`Select * from comments where tree_left <= #{XYZ.tree_left} AND tree_right >= #{XYZ.tree_right} ORDER BY tree_left`.

Inclusion of `=` in the conditions determines whether or not to include the comment being used to generate the query.

The order by tree_left is important, it puts them in nested tree order. Then in your view, you can directly iterate over this list and just indent them by their depth.

For more information on why this tree_left and tree_right stuff works, check out the Nested Set theory part of this article: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: That's a super helpful explanation. Any chance to learn SQL tricks is a plus to me. Thank you and it has really helped.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is what you are looking for. Here's a railsy example:  http://benjit.com/rails/2015/04/01/rendering-partials-with-layouts-recursively/

And here is some example code

```
#_post.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'comment_list', locals: {commenabel: @post} %>
```

This is the recursive partial:

```
#_comment_list.html.erb
<div>
  <%= commentable.to_s %>
</div>
<ul>
  <% commentable.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <li>
      <%= render partial: 'comment_list', locals: {commentable: comment} %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```